# Kendo grid override default sort

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

i have a Kendo Grid with 3 columns Title, CreationDate ans User

```
dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
....
sort: [
               { field: "CreationDate", dir: "desc" }
            ],
sortable: {
                mode: "multiple",
                allowUnsort: true
            }
....
```

the probleme is that when i try to sort by title or user, the grid sort by creationDate thenby title then by user

how can i override default "creationdate" sort

Answer (score 0):

You should set an array to your `dataSource`'s `sort` property like this:

```
sort: [
    // sort by "category" in descending order and then by "name" in ascending order
    { field: "category", dir: "desc" },
    { field: "name", dir: "asc" }
]
```

More info can be found [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-sort).

Comment: no, i want to remove creationdate from sort when i click on "title" header to sort by title

Comment: Could you try adding `sortable: {
  allowUnsort: false
}` to your grid's configuration?

PS I'm sorry for the delay. I was in a meeting...

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the problem is that when I debug my code I always find the first sort on "creationdate" I would cancel it out once the user decide to sort by title or user

Comment: I'm sorry I've mistaken the above code. You should set `sortable: { allowUnsort: true }` - the value of `allowUnsort` should be `true` so that the new sort column will apply.

Comment: yes sure, but i want to remove default sort, "creationdate"

Comment: dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
....
sort: [
               { field: "CreationDate", dir: "desc" }
            ],
sortable: {
                mode: "multiple",
                allowUnsort: true
            }
....

Comment: Please, remove `mode: "multiple"` from `sortable` property and test again. :)